# What does Tarski mean here

Tags: logic

In Tarski's book *Introduction to Logic* page 30 he writes:

"Presumably only few are aware of the fact that such terms as 'equation', 'inequality', 'polynomial' or 'algebraic fraction', which are met at every turn in textbooks of elementary algebra, do not, strictly speaking, belong to the domain of mathematics or logic, since they do not denote things considered in this domain; equations and inequalities are certain special sentential functions, while polynomials and algebraic fractions--especially as they are treated in elementary textbooks--are particular instances of designatory functions"

I can understand saying they don't belong to the domain of mathematics, but I don't see why they are excluded from the domain of logic.  On page 6 he writes:

"Algebraic equations, on the other hand, that is to say formulas consisting of of two algebraic expressions connected by the symbol '=', are sentential functions."

But in the first quote, he speaks of "this domain" not "these domains."

What's going on here?

For more context see:

[Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.com/books?id=vtzCAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA30&ots=6vw_D975cr&dq=%22do%20not%2C%20strictly%20speaking%2C%20belong%20to%20the%20domain%20of%20mathematics%22&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q=%22do%20not,%20strictly%20speaking,%20belong%20to%20the%20domain%20of%20mathematics%22&f=false)

[Equations as sentential fuctions](https://books.google.com/books?id=oKZwtLQTmNAC&lpg=PA1903&ots=Q3faBzuhOQ&dq=%22algebraic%20equations%2C%20on%20the%20other%20hand%2C%20that%20is%20to%20say%22&pg=PA1904#v=onepage&q=%22algebraic%20equations,%20on%20the%20other%20hand,%20that%20is%20to%20say%22&f=false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is alluding to the distinction between *language* and *theory*, form one side, and *metalanguage* and *meta-theory*, from the other:

From the point of view of modern logic, the (formal) theory of arithmetic is base on a language that uses expressions like :

> $x < y \, $ or $\, \, x+y=1$.

The *domain* of the variables $x,y$ is "made of" the *natural numbers*.

Thus, the (formal) expressions like the one above "speaks of" numbers.

From this point of view, concept like *equation, inequality, polinomial* do not belong to the (formal) theory, because the variables and *terms* of the theory denote *numbers* and not *expressions*.

The concepts like *equation, inequality, polinomial* denotes expressions of the (formal) theory, and thus they belongs to the meta-theory.

---

I think that when he speaks of "logic", he means the (formal) theories of pure logic : the *sentential calculus* and the *predicate calculus*.

In this sense, they are formal theory with their own "domain of discourse" : *sentences* (or *propositions*) for the sentential calculus.

In the same way as for (formal) arithmetic, the concept e.g. of *tautology* does not belong to the (logic) calculus but to the meta-theory regarding the sentential calculus, i.e. to *meta-logic*.

Comment: It's a better explanation than any I have, but there are some issues.  In the preface, he says that he will use the word 'logic' in a much broader sense.  Furthermore, the development he gives implies that sentential functions fall under the domain of logic.  But perhaps here he is using 'logic' in a different sense.  That would help explain why he speaks of one domain rather than domains.

Comment: @AndrewW - "unfortunately", I'm reading the new updated edition (1994) and thus page numbers do not corerspond. Sentential calculus (see page 33) use *sentential variables* : $p, q, r$ which stands for sentences like "$1$ is a positive number". A *sentential function* is an expression like "$x$ is prime" and belongs to *predicate calculus. It is called "sentential function" because it is a formula like $\varphi(x)$ with a variable, and thus devoided of a "complete" meaning (it has no definite truth value). 1/2

Comment: ... When the variable is replaced by a "closed" *term* (a "name" denoting an object) the result is a *sentence* i.e. a meaningful expression having a definite truth value. 2/2

Comment: But if "x is prime" belongs to predicate calculus, wouldn't that mean it is in the domain of logic?  And wouldn't equations be in the same domain?  Or are you saying that because equations have "parts" that are math and "parts" that are logic, they don't really fit into either domain?  Perhaps you could clarify, what domain would he say equations in algebra text books fall into?

Comment: @AndrewW - you are right, the example is badly chosen... In *predicate calculus* we have a *sentential function* $P(x)$, where $P$ is a (unary) pedicate symbol. When we replace the variable $x$ with a closed term (a constant) $c$ we get the sentence : $P(c)$. When we "apply" predicate calculus to formalize first-order formal theory of arithmetic, we can have sentential functions like "$x$ is prime"; when we replace $x$ with $3$ we get the (true) sentence of arithmetic : "$3$ is prime".

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the difference.  I'm still curious how you would classify such a sentence.  Would you say an algebraic equation is in the union of the domains of math and logic?

Comment: Further into the book (pg. 139), Tarski explains that sentential functions fall under the domain of "the methodology of deductive sciences" and not under logic